# How do modern cults with a following manage their logistics?

Tags: organizations, modern

I am trying to implement a cult in my world and it will be a forefront however I have been unable to find how cults do things. (My research has only led me to how to avoid cults and how to leave them which wasn't very helpful.)

The cult I was envisioning would operate under the hood of a charitable organization helping the poor get jobs by teaching them skills whilst convincing them that they are better off operating as part of the organization living in communal homes and using a communal kitchen though I imagine that all of the money transfers,creation of communes and setting up bases in new regions would attract a lot of attention from the authorities.

So my question is how do real life cults handle these logistics in a way that doesn't attract attention from authorities or invoke suspicion from the locals?

Comment: I don't fully understand why you think that cults (or communes) are illegal. They are not. Yes, the authorities will notice your cult. They will file the data to the existing list of cults, and keep tabs on you. There is no law in any civilized country saying that you cannot operate a cult. As for how to operate the communal houses, obtaining and keeping up to date power of attorney for the members of the cult etc., all you have to do is to hire a lawyer and an accountant. Preferably with previous experience, for example with the Catholic Church, Scientology, Jehova's Witnesses etc.

Comment: This was recommended for closure as off topic, but I’m voting to leave open. We’ve allowed earlier questions about military logistics and Earth-bound colonization logistics, both of which are asking for real-world examples from which to source fictional material. I put this in similar category.

Comment: @AlexP Russia and Eastern bloc nations during the Cold War had many laws against cults of any kind. Religious cults encouraged faith in something other than the state, and guild cults like the masons or glass workers (Checklosovakia) provided secret backchannels for organizing against government. I believe several major Mid Eastern nations have bans on cults, but I’m less well-read about those. There are plenty of reasons for civilized nations to limit activity of groups that have a tendency to depart from reality in their thinking. Action against anti-vaxxers has been contemplated in USA.

Comment: @SRM: That's why I said *civilized* countries. (And as a person born and raised in a former Socialist Republic, yes, I know about state repression against verious foreign religions. Note that many people in those places still believe that maybe that was not such a bad idea. Also note that *some* cults have problems with the law in Europe, especially those which make a lot of money off their followers and then pretend they don't have to pay taxes.)

Comment: I would classify the USSR as highly civilized. Oppressive, yes, but with a steady civil society. They had a functional education system, banking structure, and military complex. They went to space, for goodness sake! That kind of social undertaking cannot be done outside of civilization. Civilized does not imply democratic or libertarian. It means organized and with well defined systems for administrating social systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how do real life cults handle these logistics in a way that doesn't attract attention from authorities or invoke suspicion from the locals?

If you want to attract attention from someone, you just need to be a bother.

If you pay your bills in time, help grandma to cross the street, put your garbage bin out when it's due, keep your front garden clean, keep the music low, nobody will complain and what you do behind the door will be only your business.

Even if you are a cult, just pay your suppliers in time, keep your neighborhood happy by not being a nuisance (no noise, clean facade, etc.), do something nice for the community (picking up the trash from the park for example), and nobody will care about what you do behind the walls.

A small anecdote: when I was living in Japan, on a magazine I read about the senior representative from the neighborhood council in a city who went to complain with the head of the local yakuza clan, for the nuisance caused by the young accolades and their cars in the neighborhood. Quite surprisingly the yakuza boss apologized with the senior and duly instructed the youngster to be quiet.